# Seamless like button (without confirmation dialog)

Tags: facebook-like, localhost

I wanted to test like button for a single element in my Facebook application, first in localhost. As the url has to be reachable to facebook, I used tunneling, which already works fine for credits callback.

As one clicks on the like button, the like count increments and suddenly the like button is replaced by a "confirm" link. Clicking on it shows a preview of the content and asks for confirmation. After confirming, the count again appears for a moment and then disappears. But the news feed shows the activity.

Also when one unlikes the page by clicking the X button and selecting "Remove post and unlike" from the news feed, it always fail for the first time, but when one repeats the action, it gets unliked successfully.

The page being liked is something like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>My App</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="My App"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="game"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="<The server url that tunnels to my local machine>"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="path/to/some/image"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="My App"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="<My uid>"/>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="<My app_id>"/>
    <meta property="og:description"
          content="A sample facebook application"/>
  </head>
```

How to fix this? Is this because of testing in localhost? How to avoid the confirmation dialog, so that the user has to just click on the Like button once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'confirm' link is a clickjacking protection and will stop appearing after a period of normal use of the like button - it's not overridable manually, but will go away automatically once users are using the like button in the regular way.

Facebook's crawler will periodically re-request the URL as it's liked and if the tunnel is down it will find the URL to be down which may break existing Likes of that URL.
If possible, you should test your app using a test domain or something like that, trying to use 'localhost' or tunnel URLs may result in strange issues with caching and crawling